# mono & ubuntu: 503 -Service Unavailable => mix php & ASP.NET

Tags: php, apache, mono

I try to configure mono on ubuntu 14.04.

I think the problem is with my virtualHost.

I try to mix php and asp in the same subdomain.

The currently setup is:

- apps : ASP.NET script.
- public_html : html/php script.
- cgi-bin : perl script

In browser, I have this error when I visit http://dev.mydomain.com/apps/ :

```
Service Unavailable

The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.
```

the PHP script works fines (if I do http://dev.mydomain.com/index.php)

Nothing in apache Log.

my files setup :

```
drwxr-xr-x 7 admin admin 4096 juin   7 04:17 apps ## ASP FILES
drwxr-x--x 2 admin admin 4096 juin   7 04:05 cgi-bin
drw-rw-r-x 2 admin admin 4096 juin   7 04:05 logs
drwxr-xr-x 2 admin admin 4096 juin   7 04:05 public_html ## PHP FILES
drwxr-x--x 2 admin admin 4096 juin   7 04:05 public_shtml
```

my Virtualhost:

```
<VirtualHost xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080>
    ServerName dev.mydomain.com
    ServerAdmin info@dev.mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot /home/admin/web/dev.mydomain.com/public_html
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/admin/web/dev.mydomain.com/cgi-bin/
    MonoServerPath default /usr/bin/mod-mono-server4
    MonoPath default "/etc/mono/4.5/"
    MonoDebug false
    AddMonoApplications default "/:/home/admin/web/dev.mydomain.com/apps"
    ScriptAlias /apps/ /home/admin/web/dev.mydomain.com/apps/
    Alias /error/ /home/admin/web/dev.mydomain.com/document_errors/
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/domains/dev.mydomain.com.bytes bytes
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/domains/dev.mydomain.com.log combined
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/domains/dev.mydomain.com.error.log

<Directory /home/admin/web/dev.mydomain.com/cgi-bin>
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
<Files ~ "\.(pl|cgi)$">
    SetHandler perl-script
    PerlResponseHandler ModPerl::PerlRun
    Options +ExecCGI
    PerlSendHeader On
</Files>
<Directory  /home/admin/web/dev.mydomain.com/apps>
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    SetHandler mono
    SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI "\.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$" no-gzip dont-vary
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
    DirectoryIndex app.asp App.aspx Default.asp Default.aspx default.asp default.aspx index.html index$
    AddType application/x-asp-net .config .cs .csproj .dll .resources .resx .sln .vb .vbproj
    AddType application/x-asp-net .asax .ascx .ashx .asmx .aspx .axd .browser .licx .master .rem .site$
    MonoSetServerAlias default
 </Directory>
    <Directory /home/admin/web/dev.mydomain.com/public_html>
        php_admin_value upload_tmp_dir /home/admin/tmp
        php_admin_value upload_max_filesize 50M
        php_admin_value max_execution_time 30
        php_admin_value post_max_size  8M
        php_admin_value memory_limit 32M
        php_admin_flag mysql.allow_persistent  off
        php_admin_flag safe_mode off
        php_admin_value session.save_path /home/admin/tmp
        php_admin_value sendmail_path '/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f info@dev.mydomain.com'
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

mod-mono-server4 location:

```
root@admin:~# locate mod-mono-server4
/usr/bin/mod-mono-server4  #what I choose
/usr/lib/mono/4.5/mod-mono-server4.exe
/usr/lib/mono/gac/mod-mono-server4
/usr/lib/mono/gac/mod-mono-server4/4.2.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756
/usr/lib/mono/gac/mod-mono-server4/4.2.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/mod-mono-server4.exe
```

mono Path:

```
root@admin:~# ls /etc/mono
2.0  4.0  4.5  browscap.ini  certstore  config  mconfig
root@admin:~# ls /etc/mono/4.5/
Browsers  DefaultWsdlHelpGenerator.aspx  machine.config  settings.map  web.config
```

mono is installed:

```
root@admin:~# mono
Usage is: mono [options] program [program-options]
```

I checked on the web and people said that I need to autoConfig mono.. but if I do that.. it is not possible to run php and asp in the same folder and with my configuration.

I follow [this installation](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/linux/#debian-ubuntu-and-derivatives) and [the tutorial console hello-world](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/mono-basics/) and it works as well.

Well, The question is... what I do wrong and how can I fix it?

Thank you.

Comment: what version of mono is this? can you try with a more modern distro like ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: thank for reply. the mono version: Mono JIT compiler version 4.2.3 (Stable 4.2.3.4/832de4b). And no.. My VPS can't install the 16.04 (not listed)